# How to load image into <div> automatically without refreshing page after the image were upload to server using ajax/jquery in Java Struts 2?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2, upload

I have got the problem when I try to load image into  tag automatically without refreshing page after the image were upload to server. My project is on Java, Struts 2 framework.

This is the upload file model. (FileUpload.java)

```
package com.model;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

public class FileUpload {

    public String moveTo(String folder) {
        this.moveTo(folder, fileFileName);
        return fileFileName;
    }

    public void moveTo(String folder, String fileName){
        String fullpath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath(folder);
        File newFile = new File(fullpath, fileName);
        if(newFile.exists()){
            newFile.delete();
        }
        file.renameTo(newFile);
    }

    public boolean hasFile() {
        return file != null && file.length() > 0;
    }

    public File file;
    public String fileFileName, fileContentType;
    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getFileFileName() {
        return fileFileName;
    }

    public void setFileFileName(String fileFileName) {
        this.fileFileName = fileFileName;
    }

    public String getFileContentType() {
        return fileContentType;
    }

    public void setFileContentType(String fileContentType) {
        this.fileContentType = fileContentType;
    }

}
```

---

This is the Action of upload file. (FileUploadAction.java)

```
package com.action;

import java.io.File;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.ratngon.model.FileUpload;

@Results(value={
        @Result(name="input", location="/home/UserRegister.jsp"),
        @Result(name="success", location="/home/UserRegister.jsp")
})
public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
    // fileUpload variable  
    public FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();

    public FileUpload getFileUpload() {
        return fileUpload;
    }

    public void setFileUpload(FileUpload fileUpload) {
        this.fileUpload = fileUpload;
    }

    // Override ServletRequestAware
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }


    @Action(value="/home/upload")
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        if(fileUpload.hasFile()) {
            fileUpload.moveTo("home/common/images/user");
        }
        return "success";
    }

    public String getFlg() {
        if(fileUpload.fileFileName == "" || fileUpload.fileFileName == null ) {
            return "0";
        } else {
            return "1";
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the jsp file. (UserRegister.jsp)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<tiles:insertTemplate template="HomeMaster.jsp">
    <!-- Inclue Header from HomeMaster -->
    <tiles:putAttribute name="head" value=""/>
    <!-- Include Main Content from HomeMaster -->
    <tiles:putAttribute name="main">
        <!-- Start Tree Link -->
        <ol id="tree">
            <li><a href="index.html"><img src="common/images/icon_tree.gif" width="14" height="11" />Trang ch?</a></li>
            <li>Ðang ký thành viên</li>
        </ol>
        <!-- End Tree Link -->
        <!-- Start Right Content -->
        <div id="right_contents">
            <!-- Start Content Box -->
            <div class="contents_box">
                <h4 class="tab_title5">Ðang ký thành viên</h4>
                <div class="innerbox1_left">
                    <table class="user_infoedit" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="tab w200">User name</th>
                            <td class="t-left"><input type="text" name="input" class="form_txtarea w200" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="tab w200">User</th>
                            <td colspan="3" class="t-left"><input type="text" name="input" class="form_txtarea w200" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                    <div class="innerbox1_right">
                        <div class="userinfoedit_imagebox" id="user_img">
                            <s:if test="fileUpload.fileFileName !=''">
                                <img src="common/images/user/${fileUpload.fileFileName}" width="180" height="180" id="basic_img" />
                            </s:if>
                            <s:else>
                                <img src="common/images/user/blankavatar_l.gif" width="180" height="180" />
                            </s:else>
                        </div>
                        <div class="browse_userimage">
                            <form id ="#" name="myForm" action="upload" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input id="file_upload" name="fileUpload.file" type="file" class="inputarea" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Content Box -->
            <!-- Start Content Box -->
            <div class="contents_box">
                <div class="button_aria1">
                    <!-- <p class="btn_center_blu"><a href="#">&lt; Duy?t l?i</a></p> -->
                    <p class="btn_center_blu" id="btnDK"><a href="/upload">Ðang ký &gt;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Content Box -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Right Content -->


        <!-- Start Left Content-->
        <div id="left_contents">
            <s:include value="../include/IncCategory.jsp" />
        </div>
        <!-- End Left Content-->
        <!-- Start Feed Back-->
        <s:include value="../include/IncFeedBack.jsp" />
        <!-- End Feed Back-->
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

---

This is the jquery for load image.

```
$(function() { 
    $( "#file_upload" ).change(function() {
        document.myForm.submit();
    });
});
```

---

Now I can upload image to server and load the image back to  in the "UserRegister.jsp". But if I upload image after I wrote "user name" into the form, the "user name" wil be lost when the image is load.

So, my question is How to load the  tag automatically WITHOUT refreshing the page after the image were upload to server.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I do not use struts, so my apologize if I am not following your question. Normally, after the image is uploaded to the server, you should store a link to that image and send that back to the javascript client code. The JQuery on client side can then get the link and add it to div.

Comment: why not use jquery and ajax to upload your file

Comment: Thanks MikeNQ. I have store the link, but now I can not fresh only <div> tag.

Comment: Hi Scary Wombat, I am new in java - struts - jquery - ajax project. So please explain how to use jquery and ajax in this task. Thank you very much.

Comment: have a look at this http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Thank Scary Wombat. But in my task, the page has some text box for user input. When load image to <div> tag, the text will be lost (because the page is loaded). If the page has only <div> for image is ok. Here, I don't want to be lost the text which were input.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the client side more than the server side.
First, in order to post/submit data without reloading page, you need to use Ajax or XMLHttpRequest.

An example of using Ajax is here: [Simple example](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax)

But personally, for file upload, I would use **XMLHttpRequest** (xhr) (please note this is very similar to Ajax, the reason is that xhr has a cleaner way of monitoring upload progression, which is usually demanded for a nice uploading interface).

```
function upload(){
    // Get the files.
    var files = $('input#file_upload').files;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post','/home/upload', true);

    // Done, get the link and add it to the div.
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(status){
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            var link = xhr.responseText;
            $('div.image').innerHTML('<img src="'+link+'"></img>');
        }
    };

    // Sending request
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file',file);
    xhr.send(form);
}
```

So, in the end, with ajax (or xhr), you do not need a form tag in html to submit files at all.

[EDIT]: I have edited the url path and the input tag id to match your code. Please try again.

Comment: Thank MikeNQ for your answer. But your answer doesn't work for me.
In my page has some text box and image. First, user input some text into text box, and then select image to upload. When user select image, the image will be upload to server, and then load back from server to show on this page, but don't refresh the page (just refresh the <div> tag).

Comment: Could you explain the error or reason it does not work? You can contact me through my email as we can speak in Vietnamese for better understanding.

Comment: :) Please show me your email address, so I can contact you via email. I can't see your email in your stackoverflow account.

Comment: OMG... apart from the fact that other people may be interested in the solution, so it should preferably stay in StackOverflow (there is a permanent chat too in the comments, and is also more real time than a bazillion of mails)... NEVER PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS IN CLEAR IN A WEB PAGE :| or you will be persecuted by spammers for life

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without any refresh, you *have* to use AJAX.

If you simply want to retain some values when uploading the image, you could put those values in the upload action, and enlarge the `<form>` tag to include them (notice that both your `user name` and `user` has `input` as name, while they should differ).

Something like

```xml
<s:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <s:textfield name="username" label="username" cssClass="form_txtarea w200" />

    <!-- ... other stuff  ... -->

    <s:file name="fileUpload.file" cssClass="inputarea" />

</s:form>
```

and in the Action

```
public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
    public FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    public String username;
    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
```

---

If you have a lot of values to pass, you can create a bean (eg. InputParameters) containing your parameters, so instead of

```
    public FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    public String username;
    public Integer age;
    public String country;
```

in the Action you would have

```
    public FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    public InputParameters input;
```

and in JSP page

```xml
<s:textfield name="input.username" />
<s:textfield name="input.age" type="number" />
<s:textfield name="input.country"  />
<s:file name="fileUpload.file" cssClass="inputarea" />
```

.

If you need to use the fileupload action in a lot of forms, each one with different data to post / retrieve, you can use an interface for input parameters, or inheritance to extend a base fileupload action to cover the need of each page.

I'm not saying this is better or worse that using AJAX, it's just another way worth knowing.

P.S: using Struts tags is often better than using straight HTML... they're there to help ;)

Comment: @Bentley :  any feedback on this ?